# Neural network isn't learning for a first few epochs on Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm testing simple networks on Keras with TensorFlow backend and I ran into an issue with using sigmoid activation function

The network isn't learning for first 5-10 epochs, and then everything is fine.
I tried using initializers and regularizers, but that only made it worse.

I use the network like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import keras
from numpy import expand_dims
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot


# load the image
(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val), (x_test, y_test) = netowork2_ker.load_data_shared()

# expand dimension to one sample
x_train = expand_dims(x_train, 2)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (50000, 28, 28))
x_train = expand_dims(x_train, 3)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    width_shift_range=[-1, 0, 1],
    height_shift_range=[-1, 0, 1],
    rotation_range=10)

epochs = 20
batch_size = 50
num_classes = 10

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
                 activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(100, (3, 3),
                              activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,
                             activation='sigmoid'))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,
                             activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

With the code above I get results like these:

```
Epoch 1/20 
 - 55s - loss: 2.3098 - accuracy: 0.1036 
Epoch 2/20 
 - 56s - loss: 2.3064 - accuracy: 0.1038
Epoch 3/20 
 - 56s - loss: 2.3068 - accuracy: 0.1025
Epoch 4/20 
 - 56s - loss: 2.3060 - accuracy: 0.1079
...
```

For 7 epochs (different every time) and then the loss rapidly goes downward and i achieve 0.9623 accuracy in 20 epochs.

But if I change activation from `sigmoid` to `relu` it works great and gives me 0.5356 accuracy in the first epoch.

This issue makes `sigmoid` almost unusable for me and I'd like to know, I can do something about it. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use sigmoids as hidden activations. It is likely that the neurons "saturate" in the beginning and gradients are next to 0, so (almost) no learning happens. Once the network finally manages to leave the saturated regime, learning is fast. Relu doesn't saturate, which is why it usually works much better.

Comment: Modern neural networks don't use sigmoid activation, why are you using it?

Comment: It's not a bug, you are indeed doing something wrong, i.e. using `sigmoid` in the hidden layers

Answer (score 3):

### **Activation function suggestion：**

In practice, the sigmoid non-linearity has recently fallen out of favor and it is rarely ever used. ReLU is the most common choice, if there are a large fraction of “dead” units in network, try Leaky ReLU and tanh. Never use sigmoid.

### **Reasons for not using the sigmoid：**

A very undesirable property of the sigmoid neuron is that when the neuron’s activation saturates at either tail of 0 or 1, the gradient at these regions is almost zero. In addition, Sigmoid outputs are not zero-centered.

Comment: @Дмитрий Шаров，The problem you are experiencing is a common problem when practicing neural networks. Here are some suggestions for the selection of activation functions and why sigmoid performance is poor.

Comment: I agree with you and thank you for your answer, ReLU usually shows better results in my tests.
However I thought that optimizer guarantees that loss is getting smaller every epoch, so i'm confused about how it can go up. I've never had this problem with manually created networks

Comment: @Дмитрий Шаров，I can't get your point from your comment "However I thought that optimizer guarantees that loss is getting smaller every epoch, so i'm confused about how it can go up". Why you would expect cross entropy to rise with the number of epochs. You should know the definition of the loss function for your classification task is always to solve the optimization problem that minimizes the loss function.