# Manual predictions of neural net go wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I have a dataset (csv) with the format shown bellow:

> **First column**: random integers
>
> **Second column**: The class of each integer (called **bins**)

[image]

Bins have been made after preprocessing,for exampe integers between 1000 and 1005 belong in bin number 0 , 1006 and 1011 beongs in bin number 1 and go on.

Target column for my neural network is the column of **bins** (second column).

I use **OneHotEncoding** for my target column and transform every bin number to a binary vector. I have 3557 different bins (classes).

I trained it and evaluate it with accurancy 99,7% as a result.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/export78.csv")

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
data2 = onehotencoder.fit_transform(df).toarray()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data2)

X= dataset.iloc[:,3557].astype(float)
y= dataset.iloc[:,0:3557].astype(int)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


classifier = Sequential()
#First Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=1))
#Second  Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
#Output Layer
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

#Compiling the neural network
classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Fitting the data to the training dataset
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=10)

accr = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0] ,accr[1]))

classifier.save("model.h67")


data1 = np.array(X_test)
List = [data1]
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h67")
prediction = model.predict([(data1)])
target = (np.argmax(prediction, axis=0))
dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(target)
display(dataset1)
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I try to predict manually using my model I cant take right results.
As prediction input a give a csv with only one column with random integers and I want bins that belong as a result.
[image]

Comment: If you provide sample data that will give both you and us the same error it will be easier to figure out.

Comment: i add photos with the input datas and wrong results that i take when i run prediction

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an error message or just wrong predictions? This is not clear from your question.

Try:

```
prediction = model.predict(data1)
```

**Edit:**

> I have 3557 different bins (classes).

```
classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then `binary_crossentropy` as loss function is not the right choice, try `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: just wrong predictions......i use X_test as input in order to check the results,just for debugging but all the relusts are wrong.for example 1005 integer should give result bin 1 but prediction give bin 5 with no reason

Comment: as output i have 3557 ouputs that have values 0 or 1.....integer 1000 belongs in bin 0 so in binary vector with length 3557 ,the only 1 appeared on first column and rest of columns have value 0.For this reason i use binary_crossentropy.Is it wrong?

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is a missconception. `binary_crossentropy` is used if you have only two classes i.e. 0/1, whereas `categorical_crossentropy` is used for multiclass scenarios like yours.

Comment: It depends on the number of classes, which loss to chose not the way you encode your labels. If you wouldn't encode them one-hot but just pass them as integers, you could use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`as loss.

Comment: i understand,i use one hot so i should use categorical_crossentropy,but do you find any other mistake(ex. "sigmoid", 3557 number of outputs) because i am not sure that anything else works fine

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

To start with:

> I trained it and evaluate it with accurancy 99,7% as a result.

This is a known issue (spurious high accuracy) when one erroneously uses `binary_crossentropy` loss for a **multi**-class classification problem; see:

- [Keras binary_crossentropy vs categorical_crossentropy performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance/46038271#46038271)
- [Why is binary_crossentropy more accurate than categorical_crossentropy for multiclass classification in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327601/why-is-binary-crossentropy-more-accurate-than-categorical-crossentropy-for-multi/46004661#46004661)

Second, you are also erroneously using `activation='sigmoid'` in your last layer, where it should be `activation='softmax'`.

Third, get rid of all these `activation='sigmoid'` in the rest of your layers, and replace them with `relu`.

Last, you should get rid of all these `kernel_initializer='random_normal'` statements in your model layers; leave the argument undefined, so that it defaults to the (much superb) `glorot_uniform` ([docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/)).

All in all, here is how your model should look like:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(3557, activation='softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

That's very general advice, just for starters; a 3557-class problem is not trivial, neither is clear why you have chosen to go with 3 layers, all of them with the same number (3557) of nodes. Experiment with the architecture, keeping in mind the above points...

Comment: Well, `softmax` is really just rescaling your outputs to valid probabilities, if you use the argmax of your outputs to get a class prediction is doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will keepin mind your advice.Do you believe one hot encoding the target classes is it a good choice for my problem??

Comment: @Tinu but not with a `sigmoid` before

Comment: Regarding the hidden layer activation and the kernel initializer, these are just hyperparameters. There is no explicit law how to choose them, the ones you mentioned are just regarded as best-practices.

Comment: @Tinu what exactly is your point? it is obvious that we are talking about such best practices here (what else?). Anyone who would like to stick with `sigmoid`, claiming that there is not any "law" against it (!), well, good luck, just don't complain afterwards and wonder [why "*it doesn't learn*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608113/neural-network-isnt-learning-for-a-first-few-epochs-on-keras#comment103527313_58608113)...